# zepto javascript show x elements

Tags: javascript, html, zepto

Using zepto.js, how can You show X items from a ul, hide the rest and show them
only when the user clicks "show more" Link/button?

10X!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to accomplish what you're asking.

```
$(function() {
  $('li').slice(5).toggle();

  $('span').click(function() {
    $('li').slice(5).toggle();
  });
});​
```

The first `.slice(5).toggle()` functions take all the list items selected, narrow them down to a subset of elements that starts at index 5 through the end. Then it toggles the visible state of the first element it finds in that subset.

We then attach a function to the `click` event on the span, which is our Show/Hide element. That function is actually just the same as the initial function we ran to hide all the elements past index 5.

Check out this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPEF3/16/) for a working example. Also, for further reference here are [the docs on `.slice()`](http://zeptojs.com/#slice) and here are [the docs on `.toggle()`](http://zeptojs.com/#toggle).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 2 ways.

1. Use zepto to toggle a class and use css to define what to hide

   ```
   /* show only the first 3 list items */
   ul.collapsed li:nth-child(n+4) {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

   ```js
   var $list = $(ul.collapsed); // initially the list is collapsed

   // use a show-more link to toggle display of remaining items
   $("a.show-more").click(function(){

       // get the current state of the list by querying the className
       var shouldShow = $list.hasClass("collapsed") == true;
       $list.toggleClass("collapsed");

       // set the link text according to the task (show or hide)
       $(this).html(shouldShow ? "Show less" : "Show more");

       // its a link, don't follow it
       return false;
   });
   ```
2. Use zepto "standalone"

   ```
   var $list = $(ul);

   // use the link to set the css properties directly
   $("a.show-more").click(function(){

       var shouldShow = $list.hasClass("collapsed") == true;

       $("li:nth-child(n+4)", $list).css({
           "display": shouldShow : "" : "none"
       });

       $(this).html(shouldShow ? "Show less" : "Show more");
       return false;
   });
   ```